# English localized files doesn't load

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, string, localization

Localizable.strings for english language didn't load. It previously worked but not only I can see are the keys of the strings. On the other hand Czech strings are loaded fine. I am also aware there at least two threads about this topic, however, they didn't help me.

Summary:

1. I have two localized strings in cs.lproj and en.proj directories
2. Only Czech one is loaded.
3. The English one was previously loaded too but now only I can see are just keys.
4. I have tried to clean my project.
5. I have tried to uninstall an app from device.
6. I have tried to save Localized.strings as UTF-8 as well as UTF-16 as recommended.
7. I have tried points 4-6 at once.

Comment: Are there any error messages while building? Often a missing `"` or `;` screws up a localization file, but Xcode will issue a warning/error in this case.

Comment: All this thing is really weird as I can see English texts only with even builds. First time I don't see them, second time I see them, third time I don't etc.

Answer (score 3):

The solution: My project contained another Localizable.strings file for english language. It was inside ShareKit library. I didn't know it as I took this project over previous programmer. So I removed the file, now it works fine. Sorry for bothering you. May it can help someone other - simply search your project for Localizable.strings duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You should look inside the app package to see if your Localizable.strings file is included. To do this, right click on YourApp.app -> Show Package Contents. Look for the en.lproj folder and see if the Localizable.strings file is there. If it is, then check that its content is correct. 
Otherwise, there might either be an error in the english translation file, or XCode is acting up (I had this problem a few times - doing a clean build, restarting XCode and them a new build seemed to fix it).

Comment: Thank you! The file was inside, however, it was smaller... some texts were missing. It periodically changes. One time strings are ok, one time they are not. I am just running it without any change.